# keyless access to Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website which makes keyless access to Google Maps javascript API. The website displays maps and uses geocoding and places API. Everything happens client-side without an API key. The website was created before June 22, 2016.

According to Google Maps standard plan 2016 update, keyless websites created before June 22, 2016 are not affected by keyless access being unavailable for new domains.

However, since Friday 22, July, the website stops working properly around 8:00PM UTC (+/- 2 hours) and everything goes back to normal 4-8 hours later. Symptoms are:

- geocoding is not working at all
- places autocomplete is not working at all
- for a while after it starts maps are still loading, and then maps are not loading anymore

Are in fact keyless websites impacted in some way by the new rules? Is it temporary or should we expect this behavior to continue in the future?

Also, is that triggered by a global quota or a website-based quota?

Thank you!

Comment: I would expect if you expect it to be reliable, you should use a key.  That is what google wants everyone to do and will allow you (and them) to track usage.  The grandfathering of keyless access is to avoid breaking existing implementations and can probably be expected to have glitches as things change.

Comment: Thanks. I've been in contact with a Google Maps sales team member, who told me that this should not happen and that I should post a question on stackoverflow to figure out what's going on (as there is no support for non premium users). I was wondering if I could get some feedback from the Google technical team on stackoverflow, and/or if anyone else experienced the same thing.

Comment: The "Google technical team" doesn't seem to be around much... but maybe your experience will be different.

Answer (score 2):

just to add to what @geocodezip said:

**Also, is that triggered by a global quota or a website-based quota?**

From the [Standard Plan Updates](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update?utm_source=geoblog&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=2016-geo-na-website-gmedia-blogs-us-blogPost&utm_content=TBC):

> For the Google Maps Geocoding API, Directions API, Distance Matrix
>   API, Elevation API, and Time Zone API, ***keyless requests now have a
>   shared global quota which has been set to ensure existing applications
>   do not break***. We do not intend to raise this quota limit in the future
>   and advise all developers to use a key in order to guarantee their
>   quality of service. Applications that continue to make keyless
>   requests may experience some periodic service degradation if other
>   keyless applications' usage spikes and draws down the global quota.

**Are in fact keyless websites impacted in some way by the new rules?**

> keyless requests may experience some periodic service degradation if
>   other keyless applications' usage spikes and draws down the global
>   quota.

This might be the reason you're experiencing this.